# Run py script with python.exe from specific conda env

Tags: python, windows, conda, interpreter, anaconda3

I use Anaconda3 and a specific environment rather than the base environment for my projects. The thing is that I cannot set my .py files to open with python.exe interpreter from that environment in anaconda3\envs\env1. When I right-click a py file, go to properties and set it to open with python.exe for that env and run the script, the path showing on the terminal title bar says "anaconda3/python.exe", meaning that it is using the base python.exe, not the one from my env.
Is there a way to set this configuration? It's important for me because it is an automation script I run by double-clicking or selecting it and hitting Enter.

I was thinking if there is a way to create a bat file so the py file would open through it, the bat file would execute the command "interpreterPath/python.exe" "path/to/script.py".
The bat reads the shebang line in the script to know what interpreter to use.

**Edit**: All right, I build a solution to solve this issue, it consists in a Batch file that receives the py file as an argument, then check whether it has a shebang line (e.g. #!/usr/bin/env python) at the first line, if positive, it uses the second string (e.g. "python") as the name of the conda environment you specified in the shebang line, otherwise it uses the interpreter from conda base environment.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableExtensions disableDelayedExpansion

::Get the first line of the script
set /p text=< "%~1"

::Search for the second word of the shebang line
for /f "tokens=1-2 delims= " %%a in ("%text%") do (
  set shebang=%%a
  set env=%%b
)

::If first two characters are not #!
if not %shebang:~0,2%==#! (
    set env=
)

::Check if env is empty
if not [%env%]==[] (
    ::Env interpreter
    set PythonEnv=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\anaconda3\envs\%env%\python.exe
) else (
    ::Base interpreter
    set PythonEnv=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\anaconda3\python.exe
)

::Execute script
call %PythonEnv% "%~1"

endlocal
goto :eof
```

Answer (score -1):

You can set the python environment at the top of your python script.
Like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env /user/anaconda3/envs/test/bin/python

code
```

here change */user/anaconda3/envs/test/bin/python* to your python conda env path

Comment: My anaconda3 path is C:\Users\User\anaconda3
How would it be in that case?

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env C:\Users\User\anaconda3\bin\pythonn`

Comment: Not working. The interpreter (python.exe) is in C:\Users\User\anaconda3\envs\python

Comment: so use your path

Comment: I tried it already.

Comment: Last I knew, Windows doesn't respect shebangs.